# Best way to store Resource id in Database on Android

Tags: android, database, android-resources

In my app i want to be able to store resource id of some icons in database. I suppose it is not save to do, cause in the later stages (application upgrades) i may want to add new icons to the app, so all id's may change? What is the best practice to store resource in case i do not want to store icons as blobs?

As an example, let's say i have a game 1.0, where i let user to choose an avatar for his character from a list of avatars. I want to store this avatars id in DB and be sure that if i add more avatars in game 1.1 - user will still see his choice.

Comment: You need to be clearer. Icons are saved in the drawables folder. Why would you need to reference them in a database as well?

Comment: Ah, OK. I want to save icons that user chooses from a list that i provide, so in the later app launch to show chosen icon.

Comment: Are you talking about the app icon? Because you cannot modify the manifest after an app has been signed.

Comment: No, not the app icon, just some icons from the drawable folder. It's not about icons, but resource id. I want to store R.id chosen by user in database, without being worry of application upgrades. My concern here is that R.id generated during compile time and i am afraid it may change after adding more resources from the same type during app updates.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The best way (in my opinion) is to store the resource entry name.

```
String iconName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(R.drawable.your_icon);
```

So your SQLite database column where you want to store the icon will have type `TEXT`. You're right that storing resource IDs is a bad practice because they're recreated when you compile the app, so you can't rely on them not changing (I learned this the hard way, all my app's icons got messed up).

To get the resource ID from the String when you need it, call

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(iconName, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Note that both `getResources()` and `getPackageName()` are methods from `Context`, so you need to have reference to your application/activity Context to be able to call these methods.

Comment: Since this approach works, I am also using it, its a huge drawback regarding performance. Now I am searching for some other way (maybe cahing the drawable id once it has been retrieved)

Comment: @rimes This will not work as the id could be changed when you add new lib to code and all ids could be changed

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow With this approach I don't care about id-s. I store names of resources inside my database, and then upon launch of the app, resolve the names into id-s (so every time the app is launched, I get the latest id-s). There is a small delay when starting the app, but since I am displaying an "splash screen" it's not a problem. I also cache the id once its being resolved, which makes every other call a lot faster

Comment: @rimes Good. I think caching is a good idea, but only if you are sure that the spalsh screen will be displayed first (e.g. maybe the user opens the app from the history of activities). You would then make it lazy-initialized (at the first use of them instead of splash screen)