# Using custom binding adapter to bind drawable resource

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I'm trying to establish data binding between two properties of an object in my view model and my UI.

The object has the two properties `name` and `iconName` which I can access through Getter-/Setter-Methods in the view model.

The `name` property is a simple `String` field that gets bound to an EditText component.

The `iconName` property, however, is a **Resource Name** of an XML file located in the `drawable` directory which is supposed to get bound as the source of an ImageView component.

Changing the source of the ImageView component manually was as easy as calling:

```java
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(iconName, "drawable", getPackageName());
selectedIconView.setImageResource(resId);
```

in the Activity class.

**But now I'm not sure how to extract the resource ID inside the Binding Adapter to update the ImageView** since I seem to have no Context inside my Binding Adapter.

```java
public class SubjectAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter("app:subjectName")
    public static void setSubjectName(EditText view, SubjectEntity subject) {
        view.setText(subject.getName());
    }

    @BindingAdapter("app:srcCompat")
    public static void setSubjectIcon(ImageView view, SubjectEntity subject) {
        String iconName = subject.getIconName();
        // TODO: Set Image Resource of view
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not to store directly icon resourceId in your object? `@DrawableRes private int iconResourceId` in your `SubjectEntity` class and `imageView.setImageResource(subject.getIconResourceId())` in your `setSubjectIcon()` method

Comment: I'm storing these Entities in a Room Database. Storing the Resource ID might mix something up when adding/removing new drawables (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47797433/6920681)

Answer (score 1):

If you have any `View`, getting a `Context` is as easy as calling `getContext()` on the view.

```
@BindingAdapter("app:srcCompat")
public static void setSubjectIcon(ImageView view, SubjectEntity subject) {
    String iconName = subject.getIconName();
    Context context = view.getContext();
    String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(iconName, "drawable", packageName);
    view.setImageResource(resId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your adapter function receiving the value (resource ID):

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {

    companion object {
        @BindingAdapter("app:srcCompat")
        @JvmStatic
        fun setImageViewResource(imageView: ImageView, resource: Int) {
            imageView.setImageResource(resource)
        }
    }
}
```

This code is called from the generated class so it doesn't have to be in your viewmodel necessarily.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers my question. How is the adapter function receiving the resource ID if I only have the Resource Name?

Comment: Oh, what exactly are you passing to `app:srcCompat="@{...}"`? I assumed a resource ID.

Comment: I'm currently trying to pass through my `SubjectEntity` object which contains the property `iconName`. As you can see in my current BindingAdapter method (`setSubjectIcon`) I then get this property through a Getter.
But it`s not a resource ID. It`s "only" the Resource Name.

Comment: Could get extract it with the ImageView's context? Might help to post your `SubjectEntity` code